# For Conditional Probability, does the statement: "Given that B has occurred" imply anything on probability of B?

Tags: probability

Suppose we were to find the conditional probability: $P(A|B)$.

Does the statement: "Given event B has **OCCURRED**" imply that the probability of $P(B) = 1$?

Or does it not really imply anything?

Comment: You cannot discuss the probability of an event *after it has happened*, because then it may not even be an element of the subsequent sample space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to think of $P(A|B)$ has a hypothetical statement. It's saying *if* $B$ were to occur, then $P(A|B)$. To actually use this probability, you need to know that $B$ has, in fact, occurred. However, the mere statement of a conditional probability does not imply the conditioning event has happened.